# How to do a "Hadouken" in NES street fighter 4 (12 peoples) on Android?

Tags: android, nes, street-fighter-iv

I am playing Street Fighter 4 NES (12 peoples) on my android using NES Emulator. How can I do a "hadouken" for ryu and ken? Please suggest the controls. Thanks!

Comment: Judging by a youtube videos, it seems like it's the normal moves via onscreen buttons? Then a Hadouken is the normal thingy as seen here https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_moves_in_Street_Fighter_IV#Ryu

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for NES. I have simple up/down/left/right and a,b controls only.

Answer (score 0):

(<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) Or (<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>)